# Does Node.js/Express/Passport have an authorization module like CanCan for Rails?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Once a user is Authenticated, I would like a way to set the restrictions on what a user can view, edit and delete.  Specifically, unless they are an Admin, they can view, edit and delete ONLY files that they own. I've seen some examples with EveryAuth and Ability.js, just wondering if there is an equivalent for those using Passport.js

Comment: There is a npm module mustbe that tackles the authorization issue: https://github.com/derickbailey/mustbe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might be it can help you in achieving what you want
https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/connect-roles

Comment: How to use passport with connect-roles ?

Comment: just add the `connect-roles` middileware after passport middleware, like this: 
`app.use(authentication);app.use(connectRoles.middleware());`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/vadimdemedes/cancan is a node package written based on the Rails CanCan

example:

```
const CanCan = require('cancan');

const cancan = new CanCan();
const {allow, can} = cancan;

class User {}
class Product {}

allow(User, 'view', Product);

const user = new User();
const product = new Product();

can(user, 'view', product);
//=> true

can(user, 'edit', product);
//=> false
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)